# kibana search saved queries

Tags: kibana

Kibana has a saved queries function. It's saved globally. So if there's many Kibana users, the list of saved queries will be very long. I can't see search function to filter out a saved queries. That makes to reused a saved queries very difficult. I have to scroll through hundreds items to find it.

Is there a better way to locate a specific saved queries.